# EntityManagerFactory error after implementing Spring-JDBC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, entitymanager

So I wanted to use Spring-JDBC for using more procedures pointing to complex views, but still having JPA for Entity handling. After checking out JDBC a little and tried to implement it, I had some problem.. and I felt I wanted to go back to JPA and tackle this later.

But now.. when I try to "rollback" I'll recieve this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.expenses.expenses.Controllers.CreditGroupController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

What I've been trying:

- Rolling back the pom-file
- Run maven clean install
- Delete the target-map manually
- Running invalidate caches
- Delete the whole repository map in .m2 and run maven clean install again
- Trying to exclude some classes in autoconfiguration (Not really sure which one that should be the correct one to exclude if so)
- Enabled debug to see if I can see something suspicious, debug in spring is pretty new for me though, so I'm not so sure to know what I should look for.

It feels like the application doesn't look for the datasource configuration in application.properties anymore.

These are my dependecies that worked before i tried Spring-JDBC:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This was the dependecy I used for Spring-JDBC

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.24</version>
</dependency>
```

My main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExpensesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExpensesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Feels just like a dumb misstake.. but I need some fresh eyes with a bit more experience which probably can explain to me why this occurs..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: issue with your jars may be .  Remove version from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and remove spring-jdbc ..   spring-boot-starter-data-jpa comes with spring-jdbc already.

Comment: @MyTwoCents hey, so.. I removed the version from spring-boot-starter-jpa and the spring-jdbc is already removed. And yes I noticed that afterwards that spring-jdbc is already included in spring-boot-starter-jpa. But still I get the same error..